# Tests not picked up with XUnit testrunner on Visual Studio on Mac (C#, .net Core)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I am running Visual Studio on Mac (Preview 5, latest) and I am trying to get unit testing with Xunit working.

I created a new project for .NET Core -> Tests which creates the following 
sample code

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace SMASHDOCsTests
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void testFoo()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to compile the code properly however I can not execute the tests.

It always complains with "Internal error: unable to run tests, test discovery failed".

How can I track this error down or resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

My current version of Visual Studio for Mac is (v7.0.1.24) -- this is how I resolved the issue with the *internal warnings*:

1. Update the package nugget (located in fileTree sidebar)[image]
2. Follow the instructions on [this](https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit) page and install the extension. Note the exception for mac:

> IMPORTANT: Starting from v0.7.3, please download the .mpack files from https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit/releases Then in Extension Manager you can use "Install from file..." button to manually install this extension.

This let's me run my tests and gives me feedback in the UI:

```
[TestFixture()]
public class Test
{
    [Test()]
    public void TestCase()
    {
        int a = 100;
        int b = 100;

        Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This extension only works for non-.NET Core projects.